# Capitalize Just the last Letter in string - MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, capitalize

I have a column in my access database table, I ran a query to make it proper case by using `StrConv([MyColumn],3)` but last two letters are state names and this query makes `SOmeThing, soMethINg, NY` to `Something, Something, Ny`, 
I want the result as `Something, Something, NY`
Is there a another query I can run after to capitalize last letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
UcaseLast: Left([YourColumn], Len([YourColumn]) - 1) & UCase(Right([YourColumn], 1))
```

Comment: it gives me error that MS Access can't update all the records in the update query due to type conversion failure

Comment: That is probably due to records with _Null_ values. Filter those out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, most people would tell you to store your 'address', 'city', and 'state' as separate fields.  Then you Proper Case each separately and concatenate them together.  If you can do that... that is your best approach.

If this is a database or file that's been tossed at you and you can't make the field/table changes... it's still possible to get your desired results.  However, you better make sure all strings end with your state code.  Also make sure you don't have foreign addresses since Canadian (and other countries) use more that two letters for the province code at the end.

But if you are sure all records contain two letter state abbreviations, you can continue with the following:

```
MyColumnAdj: StrConv(Mid([MyColumn],1,len([MyColumn])-2),3) + StrConv(right([MyColumn],2),1)
```

This takes the midstring of your [MyColumn] from position 1 to the length of your [MyColumn] minus 2 (leaving off the state code) and it Proper Case's it all.

It then concatenates (using the plus sign) to a rightstring of [MyColumn] for a length of 2 and Upper Case's it.

Once again, this is dangerous if the field doesn't have the State Code consistently at the end of the string.

Best of luck.  Hope this helps. :)

Comment: its not a address field, it could be store name, some other text and in the end state,

Comment: GIGO is GIGO, as developers we sometimes can't avoid it.  I'm glad to see you found your answer with Gustav.  Just keep in mind, his answer doesn't Proper Case the first part of the string.  But I assume you already saw that and made the modifications to your satisfaction.  Best wishes :)